# Is unmarshalling thread safe?

Tags: soap, jaxb, thread-safety

I'm using the method

```
javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Source source, Class<RX> declaredType)
```

and would like to know if this method is thread safe. Otherwise I will have to instantiate an Unmarshaller on each call

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Unmarshaller.unmarshal` is not thread safe.

From: https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#other-miscellaneous-topics-performance-and-thread-safety

> The JAXBContext class is thread safe, but the Marshaller,
>   Unmarshaller, and Validator classes are not thread safe.

Comment: Thanks. Now I wonder if is it possible to attach one schema object to multiple unmarshallers who work concurrently.